# React CRA: Preload fonts from fonts folder

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, fonts, create-react-app

I am using react and using custom fonts via SCSS as:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FiraGO Bold';
  src: url('../../fonts/FiraGO-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../../fonts/FiraGO-Bold.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FiraGO Medium';
  src: url('../../fonts/FiraGO-Medium.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../../fonts/FiraGO-Medium.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FiraGO';
  src: url('../../fonts/FiraGO-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../../fonts/FiraGO-Regular.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}

// Fonts
:root {
  --font-base: 'FiraGO', sans-serif;
  --font-bold: 'FiraGO Bold', sans-serif;
  --font-medium: 'FiraGO Medium', sans-serif;
}
```

but I get to see this issue on the lighthouse
[image]

I can just use preload in a link because this is not a hosted font and hence the font files are also hashed in the build.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need to split the font file outside the SCSS build, for example, you can set it inside public HTML in the `fonts` directory and use it. (I do that for some of the external recourse and its work)

now how you can do that: (Example)

```
  <link rel="preload" href="fonts/cicle_fina-webfont.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin>
```

and then you can add:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ciclefina';
    src: url('fonts/cicle_fina-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/cicle_fina-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/cicle_fina-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/cicle_fina-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/cicle_fina-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/cicle_fina-webfont.svg#ciclefina') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Or you can move fonts and CSS for these fonts to the public HTML directory and add preload direct in index.html

Or you can add to index.html: `<link rel="preload" href="yourFont.woff2" as="font" />`